# embed ruby in coffeescript? to render a partial on ajax success and append to body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

My view has a link (remote: true) to the "new" action in the controller (HTTP "GET"), which responds with some data in JSON format... 
I want to use AJAX and have my coffeescript file append a rendered partial on AJAX success...

here is the code:

```
$ ->
$('a').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    url = $(this).attr('href')

    $.ajax
        type: 'get'
        url: url
        dataType: 'json'
        success: (json) ->
            # I want to do something like this:
            $('body').append(render :partial => "questionForm", :locals => {:q_id => json.q_id})
```

This is obviously not the correct syntax... is it possible to embed ruby into my js.coffee somehow? I've checked through everything else, and if I just do something like :

```
$('body').append(json.q_id)
```

it works - so the AJAX call and "new" action etc. all seem to be working.. Any ideas? Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning data from the server, then you probably want to use a client-side tempting system (handlebars, jquery-templates, eco) to take the json data and turn it into HTML.

If you want the server to render the HTML for you, then you can have the server render the HTML and use jquery to append it.

Something like:

```
<%= link_to "New Model", new_models_path, remote: true, id: "batman" %>
```

Then in your app/models/new.js.erb, you'd:

```
$("#batman").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "models/form", locals: {model: @model})%>");
```

Comment: @Ben if you had a coffeescript compiler in production, you can name it app/models/new.js.coffee.erb

Comment: hummm… didn't knew it was possible to chain that much. Seems logic then, but my app do not recognize it ("template is missing" error); it might requires something to be specified. Looking into it

Comment: Or that was the compiler you're talking about maybe; I did not get it all…